# Surface not casting any reflections Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

When I go into render preview, the materials from the car are not reflecting anything and are only very dark, although they should.

When going into the material preview everything seems to be okay.

I will add some pictures, so that you can see what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an image of the materials you are using. Use the tools from this site 
to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. 
See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: What's the environment that's being reflected? If the shading options (on the far right of the shading buttons) show 'Scene World', the chances are that your scene environment is not the same as your preview environment.